Declaring an init property accessor with null check in C# and without nullable analysis warnings
Recently, I encountered a problem when I tried to declare init accessor for a property in C# with some input validation and enabled nullable reference types. I would like to know if there is a simple way to avoid compiler warnings from the nullable ref types analysis. Below is a code example with demo solution to demonstrate my issue.
I declared my public class MyClass with a string Name property that should not be null.
And, because I want to be fancy and use modern C#, I decided to use init accessor syntax:
public class MyClass
{
    public required string Name { get; init; } 
}

There is one thing that concerns me about the code above. I really like when types can strictly guarantee that they are in a consistent state no matter how they are used by the calling code. I believe this is a sign of a good design. Usually, I do checks in the constructor like this:
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public MyClass(string name)
    {
       ArgumentException.ThrowIfNullOrWhiteSpace(name);
       Name = name;
    }
}

However, in with init accessor the calling code can easily create an inconsistent MyClass instance with a code like this:
var instance = new MyClass { Name = null };

I know that the nullable ref types analysis should help against this issue, but still it is not a 100% guarantee. What if MyClass is created in the context where the analysis is disabled? What if its warnings are ignored?
This is why I decided to add a check to the init accessor. First of all, I found out that I can't do this with C# auto properties. I need a backing field. So, my code transformed into this:
public class MyClass
{
    // compiler warning that non nullable _name field is not initialized
    private readonly string _name;

    public required string Name 
    { 
       get => _name;
       init
       {
           ArgumentException.ThrowIfNullOrWhiteSpace(value);
           _name = value;
       }
    } 
}

There is more boilerplate in this version. But what's even worse is that now the code has a CS8618 compiler warning about non nullable _name field left uninitialized by the default constructor. And there is no good workaround for it.
I can't mark the _name field as required, because the field is private. Even though I still can mark the Name property as required, the compiler refuses to see the relationship between the backing field _name and property Name. The only options I found are either to suppress the warning with pragma directive or to use the null forgiving operator like this:
private readonly string _name = null!;

I don't like both of them. Is there a simpler and more concise way to have a validation logic (like null checks) with init property accessors.
UPDATE:
After some discussion in the comments I have updated the code to separate the approach with input checks in constructor and focus on the code with init accessor. I would like to know if there is a simple way to make input validations with init accessors approach and without compiler warnings.
UPDATE 2:
Seems like this question is tightly tied to the following GitHub issue:
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/32358

But too much freedom and options offered in code bring complexity. For example, if you let me instantiate MyClass, why don't you either tell me to "propertize" it using init or using the constructor? What is the benefit of offering both? In the end, the syntax is (almost) the same (except for the braces vs the parenthesis). Sounds to me like the way you designed this is to fully take advantage of the parameter constructor (which offers even more control). Especially for required fields or those that need extra validation. Maybe use init for simple types or when null has less impact.

@TheNomad Suppose I am a library author. With my simple data class I want to support different styles for different people. But I find some unexpected obstacles in my attempt to do so.


What is the benefit of offering both?

Excuse me, but I don't understand your remark at all. I believe you should ask it to the C# language team first.  For example, why don't you wonder what's the benefit of having multiple ways to initialize arrays? Which one should I choose?
Why expression bodied members, there is already traditional syntax? Why add LINQ query syntax while there is a dot syntax? Why primary constructors when you can use traditional ones, which I'm supposed to pick?

@SENya it really doesn't add anything to argue about this. TheNomad gave you his opinion, which is that extra complexity comes with providing extra options (fwiw, seems to be true, at least in this case). It does no good to argue that this is a bad opinion - it doesn't help you towards getting an answer and probably makes it even less likely as it can lead to further discussion of complexity trade offs.

There is a difference between a language offering 10 methods for you to design your app (or library) and your app (or library) offering 10 methods and one or more of them providing either inconsistent behavior or even worse, a security exploit, because the code is shared across code pieces that require different rules. You are comparing apples and oranges. Frankly, it seems like you took this as a personal attack, when my question is simple: why use both, if you are worried one of them can be exploited? If others who use your lib want other features you can always add it later if they ask you.

@TheNomad I haven't taken this personally, don't worry. But I have a feeling that you might have misunderstood me. If that's the case please excuse me.
However, I still don't see how your arguments apply to my code. The argument that what is acceptable for a language is unacceptable for a library author feels very strange to me. This opinion based and in IMO it is the opposite. The language authors should be twice as cautious due to the impact they make on the language users.

I believe you should ask it to the C# language team first honestly I think the C# team is going off the rails a bit adding new features to the detriment of the language as there are now so many different ways to do things its just confusing. Now I am fulfilling my own prophecy of this discussion going off the rails ... :)

Null reference checking is one of these new confusing features and I think it is bizarre that to make things work without warnings you so often have to litter your code with null-forgiving operators. I prefer (if I am allowed) to just disable that nonsense. This may be a good test case of this - why is is so difficult to use nullable references to do something as simple as  ... well, ensuring a property is not null!

You misunderstand, I am not against it. The point I am making is I often tried to write code to "please everybody" and in the end I shot myself in the foot with bugs or complexity, instead of putting my foot down. While you should not limit or make it strict, you do need to make it clear: "it's your library, you made the design this way, that's how it should be used: non-null". So, if you won't change it to how I suggested, just put the disclaimer "I don't want you to nullify this, if you do, use it at your own risk". You won't be able to cover EVERYTHING no matter how much you try.


your app (or library) offering 10 methods and one or more of them providing either inconsistent behavior or even worse

My intent is exactly opposite. I wish to provide the consistent behavior by performing the same checks for all possible options. There are plenty of libraries that allow different use styles, starting with LINQ itself.


You won't be able to cover EVERYTHING no matter how much you try.

But in this case I can do this, like I demonstrated in the description. I'm just asking if there is a better way to do validations in the init accessor

Note that if both the constructor that takes the name and the init setter are available, then code like new MyClass("John") { Name = "Paul" } can be written.

Frankly, the constructor with parameter is declared there more for comparison of the init approach vs the constructor approach. It feels to me like too much attention is put on this minor detail which can be completely ignored. You can delete this constructor and neither the question, nor the code example won't change.
My question is "How to make in C# a simple init accessor with null check and without nullable analysis warnings?"

I assume you are getting a CS8616. It seems there is a gap in the analyzer. See "C#8 with nullable compiler only checks code in constructors before producing CS8618 warning"

If name is required and cannot be null, does it make sense to have a parameterless constructor ?

@topsail it was done because there are two constructors. If there is a constructor with parameters then the default constructor won't be generated.

@topsail Yes. The init setter can enforce that the name can't be null. Unfortunately, the analyzer that produces the CS8616 warning only looks at each constructor. And object initialization requires a parameterless constructor.

@JonathanDodds Yes, that's exactly my problem, thanks.

@JonathanDodds I haven't thought that there would be no warning on setting a property with init twice - both from the constructor and from the initializer expression. If you think about it, this may be considered somewhat ok - you are in the object creation mode.  After all, you can set readonly fields several times in the constructor.
Still, can't say I'm a fan of this.

The possibility to set property twice feels like a good argument to me against the mix of init with constructor for the same property.
Still, I feel like too much attention is drawn to the second constructor, so, I'm going to remove it from the question.

@SENya I agree that there isn't anything "wrong" with setting the property twice except for performing redundant work but, as you said, I'm not a fan.

The reason why we are all drawn to the second constructor is maybe because it is the best approach to your issue. You asked what is the best way to handle it and we (mostly or partly) said: "remove the propertization instantiation and keep the constructor" (or at least hinted to that). From my point of view, you seem keen on keeping it as you want to remove the constructor from the MRE. Sounds rather like you want some arguments on why init, the new trendy thing, is the way to go and how to fix your issue. Apart from workarounds (like the one you found), I don't think you'll find others.

What if MyClass is created in the context where the analysis is disabled? What if its warnings are ignored? - it's on the dev that uses the code to behave sensibly. If it's you, then you will. If it's not you, then it's not your problem?

I can’t agree, to me this seems to justify any bad design decision. Should we stop validating input completely then?

@TheNomad I don’t have anything against the constructor approach.

@TheNomad However, I don't want a discussion "what would be better to use in a demo scenario presented in the question?". This is not the question I asked but it seems to me that this is the question people want to answer in a roundabout way. I could see three points there - prefer constructors if you have an input validation, do not use init accessors at all, do not use nullable analysis.  I disagree with all three points. The last two are highly opinionated but I constantly use nullable ref types, and it improves the design and the reasoning about the code.

I have less experience with the init feature but I don't see why I shouldn't use it, I love the syntax. I just expect that this approach supports some input validation like the old constructor approach does. The question is asking tips to make it simpler from people who had tried the same thing. I don't want to believe that I'm the only one validating the input.

I also don't believe that constructor approach is inherently better than the init approach for input validation. It is a matter of personal preferences, and the simplicity of the code creating the object. For objects with 10 different fields I would always prefer ``init` and initializer expression over constructor.

@SENya Almost. I'd say the consensus would be to use Constructors, some pseudoInitialize(blah) method or set to validate or use more complex initialization as those provide more "support" (lack of a better word) as for null analysis that would be maybe situational. Regarding init, sure it's great, but I think it has its own place and might be used better in a different scenario. I saw some explanations where it was explained like sort of the "readonly" constructor or initializer of properties. I'd say each approach has its own place and merits and none should be disregarded.

In C#, you can declare an init property accessor with a null check by using the following pattern:
private string _myProperty;

public string MyProperty
{
    get => _myProperty;
    init
    {
        _myProperty = value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
    }
}

In this example, the init accessor checks if the value passed to it is null. If it is, an ArgumentNullException is thrown with the name of the value parameter. This ensures that the property can only be set to a non-null value during object initialization.
Use a private backing field (_myProperty) to store the property value.
Declare the property with a get accessor that returns the backing field.
Declare the property with an init accessor that assigns the value to the backing field, but throws an exception if the value is null.
This pattern allows you to ensure that the property is always set to a non-null value during object initialization, without the need for a separate null check in the constructor or other methods that set the property.

You are answering some other question. Please read my question to the end, it already includes the equivalent code.
